# Ionic - No response from $http on basic login

Tags: ios, angularjs, symfony, http, ionic-framework

We are creating a Ionic app with a Symfony api and we have a problem with $http when login on iOS. When login or password are not corrects, $http never received response from the api and timeout 30seconds later with status 0, althought everything works fine on Android with the same code (api responses are the same regardless of the platform). We tries a lot of different things but it seems like iOS refuses to receive the response for this particular request. Other requests works normally, response and status are received as expected. Below is the login request code

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(user + ':' + password);
$http.get("https://myserver.com/api/login")
.success(function(data, status) {
       console.log("success");
})
.error(function(error, status) {
       console.log("error");
});
```

Do somebody has ever encounter this kind of problem with iOS or even know how to fix it (or at least to debug it !)?
I don't know what code can make you help us so let me know !

**EDIT:**
Not found the solution yet but now I understand the problem !
When http basic response's status is 401, it set a header named WWW-Authenticate. But Cordova don't like this header (probably because of the "" in the header value) so didn't send the response to the app ...

The apache issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415
Another SO post related:
[Handling HTTP 401 with WWW-Authenticate in Cordova / Ionic iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529210/handling-http-401-with-www-authenticate-in-cordova-ionic-ios-application/30530788#30530788)

So now my problem has changed : How can I remove a header from Symfony Http Basic Authentification's response ?

Comment: Not meaning to be pedantic, but I think the .success() and .error() methods are being deprecated.

Comment: You're right, according to w3c, the good method is $http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback), but this one doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to debug without an error to look at but you could try:

- Assuming your url is not https based, your error is most likely due    to ios blocking non http requests. It can be fixed by adding this    [cordova hook](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-package-hooks#re-enable-http-for-ios9)
- Try adding your domain to the whitelist in config.xml like this `<allow-navigation href="https://myserver.com/*"/>`

Comment: Yes, the lack of error message is my bigest problem with this bug ! All my URL are https based and this request is the only one that doesn't works. Whitelist is installed and configured with `href="*"` for every parameter (I also tries `href="https://myserver.com/*"` without success)